# Laravel Migration Advantages

Tags: laravel, migration

I am new to using Laravel, and I'm currently learning about Laravel's database migration and seeding features.

It's working with the command prompt, but I can migrate and seed in phpMyAdmin as well. What are the advantages and disadvantages of migrating and seeding within Laravel as opposed to phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Laravel docs on [Migrations & Seeding](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations):

> Migrations are a type of version control for your database. They allow a team to modify the database schema and stay up to date on the current schema state.

A simple search for `why database migration` also gives me some pretty decent results. One of the easiest to understand is a page by [FlywayDB](http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/whyDatabaseMigrations.html) (I have no idea who they are until I search this term up):

> Database migrations are a great way to regain control of this mess. They allow you to:
>
> - Recreate a database from scratch
> - Make it clear at all times what state a database is in
> - Migrate in a deterministic way from your current version of the database to a newer one

The illustration they made perhaps explain it more clearly, so you may want to check it out.